# Unexpected behavoir on @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-eslint

I'm migrating a project to nx and at the moment I get following issue I don't understand.

I have three environments which are in following structure:

- `apps/my-app/src/environments/`

  - `environment.model.ts`
  - `environment.development.ts`
  - `environment.staging.ts`
  - `environment.ts`

These files have following content:

### `environment.model.ts`

```js
import { CanActivateFn } from '@angular/router';
export type Env = 'production' | 'staging' | 'develop';
export interface EnvironmentModel {
  mode: Env;
  path: string;
  websocketPath: string;
  authGuards: CanActivateFn[];
}
```

### `environment.development.ts`

```js
import { oidcActivate } from '../app/guard/auth.guard';
import { EnvironmentModel } from './environment.model';
export const environment: EnvironmentModel = {
  mode: 'develop',
  path: 'http://localhost:8080',
  websocketPath: 'ws://localhost:8080',
  authGuards: [oidcActivate],
};
```

### `environment.staging.ts`

```js
import { oidcActivate } from '../app/guard/auth.guard';
import { EnvironmentModel } from './environment.model';
export const environment: EnvironmentModel = {
  mode: 'develop',
  path: window.location.origin,
  websocketPath: `wss://${window.location.host}`,
  authGuards: [oidcActivate],
};
```

### `environment.ts`

```js
import { dropRouting } from '../app/guard/auth.guard';
import { EnvironmentModel } from './environment.model';
export const environment: EnvironmentModel = {
  mode: 'production',
  path: window.location.origin,
  websocketPath: `wss://${window.location.host}`,
  authGuards: [dropRouting],
};
```

So for me everything looks fine but when I run `npx nx lint my-app`

I get following linting issues:

```
..../apps/my-app/src/environments/environment.staging.ts
  5:3   error  Unsafe assignment of an `any` value                @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
  5:9   error  Unsafe member access .location on an `any` value   @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
  6:27  error  Invalid type "any" of template literal expression  @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions
  6:27  error  Unsafe member access .location on an `any` value   @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
```

I don't know why this fails on the `environment.staging.ts` file while it works fine on `environment.ts`?

Can someone please explain it to me?

`update:`

the `oidcActivate` is a CanActivateFn defined like this:

```js
export const oidcActivate: CanActivateFn = () => {
  const oidcSecurityService = inject(OidcSecurityService);
  const router = inject(Router);

 return oidcSecurityService.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
    take(1),
    map(({ isAuthenticated }) => {
      if (!isAuthenticated) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('redirect', window.location.pathname);
        return router.parseUrl('/callback-auth');
      }
      return true;
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: what is `oidcActivate`, could you post that

Comment: @terahertz this is a simple `CanActivateFn` I'll update the question

Comment: It looks like eslint is mad about line 11. Your paste only has 8 lines. Which line exactly is it failing for?

Comment: @Jason damn, I removed comments for readability. It is complaining about `window.location.origin` and it seems that window is interpreted as any accessing `.location` is unsaved.